# Listview items are not scrolling after applying fixed/static Listview Height

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

In our `ListView` when items are less but `ListView` height is greater (as set to static) than the items, at a particular position, the `Listview` stops scrolling.

We have implemented `HasUnevenRows="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"` according to the solutions that we could have.
(we have already tried setting the `ListView` height dynamically, but it does not solve our issue.)

Our `Listview` is inside a `Grid` and we are not having any `ScrollView` on our page.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                      Grid.Column="0"
                      HasUnevenRows="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      SeparatorColor="#3A69A5"
                      SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ItemNameList}"
                      CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                      HeightRequest="700">
```

Comment: You could post the full code of  xaml and code behind .  The above code seem has no issue .

Comment: Have you tried setting `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` to true?